# Sort List<List<Integer>> by first number in each sub-list

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, data-structures

I came across the following problem. I have an ArrayList(1) of ArrayLists(2). What I need to do is, to sort the structure so that the first elements of ArrayLists(2) to be in ascending order going down ArrayList(1). To clarify:

Input:

```
3, 8, 6
2, 14, 205, 44, 1
1, 3
```

Output:

```
1, 3
2, 14, 205, 44, 1
3, 8, 6
```

Look how it sorts the rows only based on the first value.

For now the way the arraylist of arraylists is defined for me is:

```
List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
// and I add elements to it likewise
graph.get(currentIndex).add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

The reason I am using ArrayList is because I read that it is more memory efficient than LinkedList and because I am building a list of adjacency lists of a graph. In it both either the number of nodes can vary or the length of the adjacency list per node. The first element of a row is the `start_node`, the following - its adjacent. Could you please tell me how can I implement this sorting?

Comment: `more memory efficient` - try to read abou `LinkedList` advantages,. For adjacency list you should use `LinkedList`.

Comment: You can wrap the List in an object and then implement the `Comparable` interface. Inside there, in the `compareTo` you can implement your logic. Also, `LinkedList` has worse cache locality so you can get worse performance because memory allocation isn't continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as I understand it, you want to sort the top-level list by the first element of each nested list. Is this correct? Here is how I would go about it:

```
List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
// add a bunch of things ...
// ...

// Now, to sort:
graph.sort((x,y) -> Integer.compare(x.get(0), y.get(0)));
```

This is using `Integer` to get a `Comparator`, which is what the `sort()` method requires to sort by some custom criteria. In this case, we are telling it to sort the `List` of `Lists` `graph` by comparing two arbitrary items in `graph` by getting their first items and comparing them as you normally compare `Integer`s.

Note that this assumes all items in `graph` **have** a first item.

Comment: By the way - you could be even more terse (intellij suggests replacing what I wrote above with `graph.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.get(0)));`) But I like the above because it's easier to understand

Comment: I don't understand. Seems like I am doing something wrong. I am getting an Index out of bounds exception. The sorting code is literally the line you suggested. `Vertical length of list: 3 // it indeed is 3`                                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at BFS.lambda$main$0(BFS.java:113)

Comment: I want to appologyze, I had a regression in my code. Your idea works perfectly, very short and elegant. I came up with another solution which I will write down at the end of the post.

Answer (score 1):

To compare 2 sublist you need to find the first non-equal pair, and compare their value (if both starts with like `32`, you need to look next value to see)

```
List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
graph.add(Arrays.asList(3, 8, 6));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(2, 14, 205, 44, 1));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(2, 14, 205, 44, 2));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(1, 3));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(1, 4));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(1, 4));
graph.add(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 5));

graph.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int indice, cmp, min;
    for (indice = 0, min = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size());
         indice < min; indice++) {
        if ((cmp = Integer.compare(o1.get(indice), o2.get(indice))) != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    if (indice == o1.size()) return -1;
    if (indice == o2.size()) return 1;
    return 0;
});

System.out.println(graph);

[[1, 3], 
 [1, 4], 
 [1, 4], 
 [1, 4, 5], 
 [2, 14, 205, 44, 1], 
 [2, 14, 205, 44, 2], 
 [3, 8, 6]]
```

---

As side, another way using `Comparator` interface (I agree this is not very nice), it compares the value until one of the list if empty, then it will compare the size if it reaches one fully

```
graph.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    Comparator<List<Integer>> cc = Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.get(0));
    int indice, min;
    for (indice = 0, min = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size()); indice < min; indice++) {
        final int i = indice;
        cc = cc.thenComparingInt(l -> l.get(i));
    }
    return cc.thenComparingInt(List::size).compare(o1, o2);
});
```

Comment: Out of bounds exception if o1 equals o2 or if one is a prefix of the other

Comment: @azro, I tried both your solutions. The two ifs in the end mean, if all elements so far of both lists are equal - return smaller, the one which is shorter? My input is 2 4 | 1 3 | 5 47 99, and I expect the first two to switch order. After sorting prints: [] [] [2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 47, 99] . I tried both with ArrayLists and LinkedLists - the same result.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is another solution I came up with.

The idea is: use the Collections' static method sort() and feed it in with the reference to the list and a new Comparator object with defined by us compare().

```
Collections.sort(graph, new Comparator<List<Integer>>(){
@Override
public int compare(List<Integer> aList1, List<Integer> aList2) {
   return aList1.get(0).compareTo(aList2.get(0));
}
}));
```